# How to save geolocation?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, save, location

Alright, I know this is probably really easy but I don't know much haha. So what I am trying to do is save my current location. So with this code, I can get my current latitude and longitude but how would I go about saving it and be able to see all the locations that I have saved. I am trying to get a button going where if pressed I will be able to view the different locations I saved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? This would let you save data in the browser and persist across refreshes and sessions. Or are you trying to push the data to a server?

Answer (score 0):

Here if the location is previously set in localStorage then that print otherwise when the user clicks on a button that location object store in the localStorage.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQGZvd) is live demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <p id="prevLoc"></p>
    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()" id="getLoc">Get Location</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      if(localStorage.getItem("loc")) {
        // json to object
       var loc = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loc")); document.querySelector("#prevLoc").innerHTML= `<b>PREVIOUS LOCATION</b><br />LAT:${loc.lat} LONG: ${loc.long}`;
      }
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      localStorage.setItem("loc", JSON.stringify({
        "lat": position.coords.latitude,
        "long": position.coords.longitude
      }));
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```